# vsCode does not show Java intelliSense

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, intellisense

I received a new Amazon Workspaces workspace and have been running into the following error:

```
"Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 
'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-bin.zip'.
Gradle 6.8 requires Java 8 or later to run. Your build is currently
 configured to use Java 7."
```

The app compiles and runs fine, I just get no intelliSense help.

Current Java installation uses:

```
openjdk 11.0.19 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.19.7.1 (build 11.0.19+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.19.7.1 (build 11.0.19+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

The `build.gradle` file sets the version:

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.11'
targetCompatibility = '1.11'
```

The recommended Java extension is installed: `Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat`

I'm not quite sure how to set the java runtime version within vsCode and get it to take.  When attempting the change the setting, there is no Java version set (see image below). The edit button takes me to the build.gradle which sets the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility`.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Might be the same problem](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, 3 versions of Java were installed on the workspace.  Finding the correct JVM and setting the Gradle daemon to use it solved all of my issues.

[image]